# How to control OptionMenuItem from fragment and MainActivity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, menuitem, optionmenu

I have an option menu item on my action bar, in this option menu i have 
4 items one of them is logout. 
well logout item i control it from MainActivity (it's work)
the problem is how to control the other 3 items from the fragment because i need to use some objects and methods from fragment Class 
so there is any solution to control the 3 items from fragment and the logout item from the MainActivity ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create and handle option menu items in fragments as follows:

1. In `onCreate` or `onCreateView` call [`setHasOptionsMenu(true)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setHasOptionsMenu(boolean))
2. Override [`onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu, MenuInflater)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu,%20android.view.MenuInflater)) and inflate
   the fragment related menu there
3. Override [`onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)) and handle menu
   option clicks there

Comment: when i Override onCreateOptionMenu i have the Error : "Methode does not override method from its superclass" !!

Comment: in the other hand onOptionsItemSelected doesn't generate any error

Comment: well I solved it using super.onOption... and you answer was helpful ... thank you so much